# Failure and successful probability in first and second attempt

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose successful probability of the first attempt is $P_1=e^{-\theta}$ where $\theta$ is real. If anyone know how we can get using any probability low or any distrubution the probability of failure in first attempt $Q_1$ and  the second attempt $Q_2$ and success in the second attempt $P_2$ given that 
$$
P_1+P_2+Q_1+Q_2=1
$$ 
I mean suppose we send a message in the first attempt it can decode correctly with $P_1$ or incorrectly with $Q_1$ if it decodes incorrectly in the first I will send in the second attempt but now I will combine the first incorrectly decode by the second receive message, now if this two combined decode correctly so this is with probability $P_2$ else it will be decode incorrectly with  $Q_2$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If probability of success in the first attempt is $e^{-\theta}$, then probability of failure in the first attempt is $1-e^{-\theta}$. In the event of failure for the first attempt, there is a second attempt which either results in success (with probability $P_2$) or failure (with probability $Q_2$), so $P_2+Q_2=1$ as well. It does not make sense to have $P_1+P_2+Q_1+Q_2=1$. Do the attempts succeed/fail independently of one another? We need to know this if we want to calculate $P_2$ and $Q_2$.

Comment: ok but hat if they depend and howw e compute second attempt  thanks

Comment: If the success of the second attempt depends on the first attempt, then we do not have enough information to proceed. If they are independent, then $P_2=P_1$.